# Переназначение горячих клавиш Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, hotkeys

Хочу переназначить горячие клавиши в google chrome для перехода по вкладкам, сейчас комбинация для перехода (ctrl+tab - next / ctrl+shift+tab prev) не очень удобная, хочу переназначить на другую комбинацию, к примеру на боковые кнопки мыши, но инфы по этому крайне мало. Кто знает как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

На англоязычном superuser есть подобный вопрос "[How to customize Google Chrome keyboard shortcuts?](https://superuser.com/questions/497526/how-to-customize-google-chrome-keyboard-shortcuts)" и в комментарии к нему есть линк на плагин. Попробуйте

> Have you tried searching the Chrome Web Store? If not, here's a link to a shortcuts manager extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck

Comment: При цитате ответов с англоязычного SO следует давать ссылку на сам ответ, как того требует копирайт.

Comment: Вы опередили меня, это неудобно с мобилы, поэтому в несколько итераций сохранения

Comment: Я установил указанное расширение, но оно не изменяет горячую клавишу **Ctr+k**. Может кто знает как ее удалить из Хром? (ОС Windows 7)